# Alternate name for Sand traps

Tags: word-request, idioms

Is there any technical name for the sand traps in some car races? I mean, those areas covered with soil and designed to prevent a car from hitting a track wall.

Answer (score 1):

They are usually actually "gravel traps", and are a type of "[run-off area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-off_area)".  Theese seem to be the technical terms, but they are quite understandable "gravel filled area to trap run-away cars" and "an area for cars to run off the track into".